# please help me with a Hud bug i think

Tags: texturing

i'm making a intro in blender 2.76b .when i click compositing i don't see the view , select , add ... if you don't understand, here's 2 screenshot (i took one from a video)

the one from the video (How i want it to look like): https://gyazo.com/860ad6fe11fbf8bd6d08af09be01dd82

my verision 
https://gyazo.com/939c74bf17570d67a50afa2ce713fce1
but the thing is that when i start i new prodject it looks normal again and then i switch to my prodject it isn't there! please help me (Sorry if i used wrong tag)

Comment: Welcome! Click the "+" on the bottom right to reveal the bar. There is should already be a more in-depth explanation somewhere on the site. I'll link as soon as I foud it.